# How to Proxy a Promise in JavaScript es6

Tags: javascript, proxy-classes, es6-promise

I'm trying to Proxy a Promise in native Firefox (and using Babel).

```js
var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){resolve(42)});
var promProxy = new Proxy(prom, {});
promProxy.then(function(response){console.log(response)});
```

This doesn't work, I get 'TypeError: 'then' called on an object that does not implement interface Promise.'

Comment: *Why* are you trying this? Indeed, a proxy for a promise is not a native promise object. Maybe you were looking for subclassing?

Answer (score 10):

You need to have your handler [implement the get() trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) and return the *bound* version of `prom.then`

```
var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){resolve(42)});
var promProxy = new Proxy(prom, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    if (prop === 'then') {
      return target.then.bind(target);
    }
  }
});
promProxy.then(function(response){console.log(response)});
```

Note that if you simply want to proxy *all* accessors, the `get` function would look like this:

```
var promProxy = new Proxy(prom, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    var value = target[prop];
    return typeof value == 'function' ? value.bind(target) : value;
  }
});
```

`bind` will ensure the function won't be incorrectly called when you're dealing with Native objects such as Promises, or the console.

EDIT: In some instances browsers / node will have an outdated version of Proxies, in which case you'll want to use [harmony-reflect](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect) to bring it up to date.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, this question is **How to Proxy a Promise**. I arrived here looking for **How to Promise a Proxy** -- or maybe more precisely, **How to resolve a Proxy**. I suspect others may land here, too, so I'll post this here, just in case.

I already have a nice working proxy object, and then I go and try to wrap it in a promise:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var proxy = get_my_proxy();
  resolve(proxy);
});
```

And wouldn't you know it, then darn resolve method asks my proxy for a `then` property (which is unexpected by my proxy logic, causing it to throw). It may not be ideal, depending on what your proxy is for, but here's how I worked around this (and appropriately enough, as my question is the inverse of this one, my solution is the inverse as well) -- by returning `null` for `then` -- thereby letting `resolve()` know that I didn't pass it a `Promise` (aka `Thenable`).

```
get: function(target, prop) {
  if (prop === 'then') return null; // I'm not a Thenable
  // ...the rest of my logic
}
```

Comment: just ran into this, appreciate the answer

Comment: This saved my hair from being pulled.